# How would I get my slide deck to show on my home page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have my slide deck hidden on every page but I would like it to be visible on my home page how would I do this using jquery? here is a live demo http://epecho.com/tst/index.html

Comment: Please post the relevant code, markup and css within your answer.

Comment: Also, if it's not to be displayed, it should not be necessary to include the markup (at least) in every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JavaScript that shows/hides the slide show that is on your page:

```
$(".toggleButton").click(function() {
    $("div#sliderSection").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".toggleButton").toggle();
});
```

Using the *window.location.href* (as suggested by Andreas) function you should do something like:

```
if(window.location.href==url){
    $('div#sliderSection').slideToggle('slow');
    $('.toggleButton').toggle();
}
```

I suggest the following extra modifications:

1. Refactor the code to show/hide into a function and call it in both the above functions.
2. Think about edge cases for the url comparison. The following URLs '\index.html', '\Index.html', '\' all should match.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

What about checking for the `location.href` to be the home scren url?

```
if ( location.href == "http://epecho.com/tst/index.html" ) {
    $('SLIDE_DECK').show();
}
```

I dont know if this is all you need?